# In this tutorial, why does it tell us to mess with the $_POST['email']?

Tags: php, mysql, security

http://php.about.com/od/finishedphp1/ss/php_login_code_4.htm

I am really confused about three particular lines of code in this tutorial to create a login page and databse, on the page I have listed above.

```
if (!get_magic_quotes_gpc()) {

        $_POST['email'] = addslashes($_POST['email']);

    }
```

Why is she fiddling with the $_POST['email'] value, when it isn't even in an input box?

EDIT:

I still cannot find an input box for email, I have even copied and pasted the entire site. I still can't find one box that says email.

Comment: must have copied the code from somewhere.. :D

Comment: That IS from an input box (read the comments on that page, they say ` //if the login form is submitted `). And, by the way, it's awful code. Really awful.

Comment: I still don't see where email is coming from, the registration page doesn't use email, and login doesn't use email either... Does anybody have a better idea for a better login tutorial?

Comment: That site has horrible coding and horrible format to learn from. Try this one. http://www.phpeasystep.com/phptu/6.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, it doesn't matter where the content comes from on the page.  Any user-submitted content (i.e. anything in the `$_GET`, `$_POST` or `$_COOKIE` superglobals) should be treated as unsafe.  Don't presume that the only way a user can submit evil content is by typing it into a textbox.

Second, this code is, IMO, dumb.  It basically says "if [magic quotes](http://php.net/manual/en/security.magicquotes.php) are off, do what they'd have done if they were on, by adding slashes to avoid SQL injection".  It's the lazy way to make your code work.  The proper way is to build your code so that magic quotes are unnecessary, by using parametrized queries (e.g. using PDO or mySqli).

Basically, from that line of code, you can tell enough to know that you shouldn't trust the rest of it.

Answer (score 1):

When a form is submitted (via `POST`), you can access the data **server-side** with the special variable `$_POST`. Each item of your form will be indexed in that array, give its DOM name.

So the point here, is to check the server configuration, and if the behavior to automatically add slashes to the input (to avoid SQL injection), then this action is performed by the developper. This is to avoid double addslashes which leads to crappy output.

See: [super globals](http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.external.php), [sql injection at owasp](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/SQL_Injection), and [magic quotes](http://php.net/manual/en/security.magicquotes.php).

Answer (score 0):

`email` is probably set by a form on another page that links to this page.  As for writing directly to _POST, I don't think there is anything wrong with it per se, but I think it is weird and I don't like to do it.  In fact, I would do the opposite and strip slashes if magic quotes is enabled and handle the escaping of it later (rather than with mysql_real_escape_string).  Before handling a _POST, value I would do something like `$email = $_POST['email']`... etc. and just keep _POST as the raw _POST data the whole time.